# For loop ends itself and terminates the running program but runs correctly when the slope calculation statement is removed

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am scanning the candidate ROIs of an image for lines using the Probabilistic Hough Line function of opencv and then calculating the slope of each detected line. The inner  For loop ends itself and terminates the running program if the no. of lines detected for each ROI is greater than 5, but runs correctly when the slope calculation statement is removed. I am using eclipse Luna 4.4.0. Mat ini[] is used to store each candidate ROI

```
for (int m = 0; m < cnt; m++)
{
    if (selected[m] == true)
    {
        vector<Vec4i> lines;
        vector<Vec4i> v_lines;
        vector<Vec4i> h_lines;
        int vl_cnt = 0;
        int hl_cnt = 0;

        // lines are detected in rectangle number m
        HoughLinesP(ini[m], lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 40,
                             (ini[m].cols) / 3, (ini[m].cols) / 5); 

        float slope = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
        {
            cout << "0";
            Vec4i p = lines[i];
            cout << "1";
            slope = ((p[3] - p[1]) / (p[2] - p[0])); // removing this statement fixes the unexpected termination
            cout << slope;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger, and make sure that `p[2]-p[0]` is not zero when the crash happens. Then add a check for that case.

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a divide by 0 error, the problem went away when I added this before the slope calculation: if((p[2]-p[0])==0)
             {
              continue;
             }

Comment: Now, I want the slope of vertically straight lines as well, so how should I do that without ignoring the 0 values –

Comment: Sorry, just realised there is no need to calculate the slope of vertical lines. Thankyou so much @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a *divide by zero* error when `p[2] - p[0] == 0`.  Simply guard against it with something like:

```
float run = p[2] - p[0];
if (run != 0) {
    slope = ((p[3] - p[1]) / run);
} else {
    // handle no run 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like a divide by 0 error, the problem went away when I added this before the slope calculation: if((p[2]-p[0])==0)
             {
              continue;
             }

Comment: Now, I want the slope of vertically straight lines as well, so how should I do that without ignoring the 0 values

Comment: @AdityaSanghi The *slope* of "vertically straight lines" is infinity.

Comment: oh sorry, no need to calculate the slope, the ignored case can be used for the vertical line itself